# Android MediaPlayer stop() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Pretty much the title. Using ListView, on clicking on an item, the suitable raw file id is passed to the playsound method. The start() is working fine, but stop() doesn't do anything.

```
public class AmbienceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer sound;

    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
            "Breeze",
            "Birds Chirping",
            "Rain on Window",
            "Cafe"
    };
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ambience);

        SoundsList adapter = new SoundsList(AmbienceActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.soundslist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if(position==0)
                    playSound(R.raw.breeze);
                else if(position==1)
                    playSound(R.raw.birds_chatter);
                else if(position==2)
                    playSound(R.raw.rain_on_window);
                else if(position==3)
                    playSound(R.raw.cafe_chatter);
            }
        });
    }

        protected void playSound ( int x){
            int soundPlaying = 0;
            sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,x);
            if (x != soundPlaying && sound != null) { //Play a new sound
                sound.release();
                sound = null;
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, x);
            } else { //Play sound
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, x);
            }

            if (sound != null && !sound.isPlaying()) {
                sound.start();
            } else if (sound != null && sound.isPlaying()) {
                sound.stop();
            }

            soundPlaying = x;
        }
    }
```

The playing variable is initialized to zero in the Activity's main method (and onItemClick is a part of it).

Comment: Try to call reset() instead of stop().

Comment: @Raj no effect :(

Comment: Can you provide more code so I can recreate the issue you are describing (like post the activity)? It is possible **playing** isn't being set correctly on multiple calls to **playSound()**... Or what I mean is I am not seeing enough code to say where the issue is, what you posted looks fine

Comment: @ViaTech Sure. Look at the updated question.

Comment: @harsh99 i have added a proyect using the method suggested in my answer, check this example: https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-MediaPlayer-play-sounds-in-ListView

Comment: @Jorgesys Thanks for that but - wait for it - the stop() still doesn't work TT. Clicking on a playing listitem just restarts the media. And how can I also add the image files in the ArrayAdapter initialization? I'm really new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `MediaPlayer` instance everytime you call `playSound()` method, this is incorrect and this is basically the problem, do this:

```
private MediaPlayer sound;
protected void playSound (int x){
    //MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,x);
    if(sound != null){
         sound.release();
         sound = null;
         sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,x);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

now, you don´t need a variable to detect if `MediaPlayer` is playing, use the method `isPlaying()` and then if it is playing just stop with `stop()` :

```
private MediaPlayer sound;

protected void playSound (int x){
    int soundPlaying = 0;
    //MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,x);

    if(x != soundPlaying && sound != null){ //Play a new sound
        sound.release();
        sound = null;
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,x);
    }else{ //Play sound
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,x);
    }

    if(sound != null && !sound.isPlaying()) {
        sound.start();
        //playing = 1;

    } else if(sound != null && sound.isPlaying()){
        sound.stop();
        // playing = 0;
    }

    soundPlaying = x; //current id of sound.
}
```

Comment: Now it's not playing anything. Please check the updated question to see if you can find my mistake. I've now included the entire activity.

Comment: Overall that is the OPs problem, I have seen this exact issue before; if you call multiple initiations of MediaPlayer, the system doesn't know which one to close. You need to set a class variable for that and open/close the same variable. I did not notice the MediaPlayer being called on every call to **playSound()** initially. Nice.

Comment: Okay, I stupidly didn't remove your commenting. But the stop() still doesn't work.

Comment: @harsh99 ok check my update of the playSound() method this will help to solve your problem

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work. A funny thing I've noticed: if I click it again, another instance of the file starts playing. If I click another view, then the associated file plays simultaneously as well.

Comment: Do you have declared: private MediaPlayer sound; ?